# A 'native text' file appears on my desktop whenever I launch Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Whenever I start Minecraft a file called native text appears on my desktop. It is called 'Native file', and it is just a bunch of locations and junk that makes no sense to me.

If I delete it and start up Minecraft it reappears.

What does this file do? What is it's purpose? Please tell me what is going on. No mater what I do it will still not go away it comes back. Mods and feed the best,etc. there might be something corrupt about my minecraft, profile.

Comment: What native text file, what is in it? What is it called?

Comment: We will need more information in order to help you.

Comment: I'm 100% confident the actual filename is `nativelog.txt`. Minecraft creates a log of the startup process (setting the run directory, etc) in `nativelog.txt` upon startup in the same directory as Minecraft.exe.

Comment: I will correct that.

Comment: Your latest update isn't needed; it has nothing to do with the problem you're facing. Questions aren't closed because they're answered, either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because minecraft is putting files from the game in your desktop. If you do not want this, simply change minecraft directory by doing putting the launcher shortcut in a folder.

If this is still really annoying, and you don't want to put it in a folder then you can save this (.BAT extenstion is a must!):

```
echo off
goto del
set Desktop=C:\Users\Joey\Desktop\ & rem MUST CHANGE THIS TO WHERE MINECRAFT IS LOCATED
cd %Desktop% 
if exist nativelog.txt (del /q nativelog.txt)
goto del
```

Then run this to delete NativeLog.txt whenever it is possible. note it will still be in the recycling bin.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the post. He means nativelog.txt, btw. why you ppl so harsh?

Comment: We strive to give the ***right*** answers. You might be very well correct that it's `nativelog.txt`, but we want to be sure that's what we're dealing with.

Comment: @Whaaaaaat We strive to provide expertise. Being able to figure out what an asker is actually talking about based on knowledge about the game is more valuable to the site than asserting that an asker must have meant exactly what they said, therefore answers that don't mention a file called `native file` are probably wrong.

Comment: The location of the shortcut to the launcher is completely irrelevant,  the folder it is executed in matters. That is typically the location of the launcher itself. Your batch file fixes a symptom rather than the issue.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: He is either running the exe directly from the desktop (hence the file there), which is not intended.  Or else the shortcut's "run in" (don't know the exact term) is set to his desktop for some weird reason (unlikely).